# tzsk\payu package for laravel 7.3.0 after payment redirect gives 419 error

Tags: payment, payumoney, laravel-7

I have installed version of laravel 7.3.0. and installed a package for payumoney tzsk\payu(4.0). It works well till the payment. after payment done when it redirects back it gives 419 error. 
This is the url I am getting after payment process done.
http://127.0.0.1:8000/tzsk/payment/success?_token=RNZTbKx8Ru1VWa2rasf sad9fq9qLcttbtPvDJXpYM&callback=aHR0cDovLasdfasdfasdfbnQtcGFja2FnZS1wYXltZW50L3N0YXR1cw==

You can also generate this error by installing new laravel and tzsk\payu package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tzsk have fixed this issue in his package for temporary. Please check at https://github.com/tzsk/payu for more information. 
Added following code in src/Controllers/PaymentController.php

```
class PaymentController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Temporarily set cross site on
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        config(['session.same_site' => null]);
    }
```